# jquery - function not defined - calling this function from inline script

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, inline-scripting

I have the code as shown below. Have removed unwanted code from this, just wrote what was needed. When I call my toggleFunc from inline script in body, it shown in console that this function is not defined. Can anyone please tell me whats wrong with this?

```
<head>
<script src="~/Client/js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var pageInitialize = function () {  

            ..doing something here

            function toggleFunc() { 
               ..doing something more here
            };
        };
        pageInitialize();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>toggleFunc()</script>
</body>
```

Comment: That is because `toggleFunc()` gets called before it is defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both your functions will not be defined until DOMReady has fired, which will happen after the call to `toggleFunc` in the `body` has been run. Also, `toggleFunc` is within the `pageInitialize` function, and is therefore not accessible outside `pageInitialize`.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pageInitialize = function () {  
        //..doing something here
    };
    pageInitialize();

    function toggleFunc() { 
        //..doing something more here
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks man, I kind of realized just after posting the question. Stupid question, I ask at times. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Is there a way that if the function is defined then call the function?

Comment: @C-linkNepal yes, you can check if the function exists before calling it: `functionName && functionName();`

Comment: No, I meant when the OP calls toggleFunc() inside script then if it is ready to use then call it???

Comment: @C-linkNepal no. All you can do is check if a function is available to use at a specific time. There is no way to know when a function become available to you.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. `toggleFunc` isn't a global function. It's local to `pageInitialize`. If you want it to be global, assign it to `window`.
2. You're defining the function inside a `$(document).ready` callback, which will execute at some point in the future. You're invoking the function immediately, *outside* a `$(document).ready` callback. It won't have been defined yet.

Answer (score 0):

`toggleFunc()` is a [Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) unable to be called from the global scope.

It's also being called before it's even defined as you are using `$(document).ready`